# how to read specific file while passing multiple parameters in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, function

I am trying to read specific big query table by passing argument value in my function, so depends on which argument value I pass, my function should read specific datatable. To do so, I was able to write this in python, but I feel like this is not quite elegant. I tried to use `*args` and `**kwargs`, but seems `**kwargs` could be better way to handle this but my current code has some syntax error. Can anyone look into my code and suggest possible way of improving this function?

**my current attempt**:

this is my first function to read file based on parameter value:

```
# !pip install pandas-gbq
import pandas as pd

def _readbqTble1(project_name='fb', dataset_name='iris',which_dim='lifespan', which_src='asia'):
    def str_join(*args):
        return '_'.join(map(str, args))

    table_name =  str_join('inst_pic',{*which_src},{*which_dim})
    query = "select * from `{project_name}.{dataset_name}.{table_name}`".format(project_name=project_name,dataset_name=dataset_name,table_name=table_name)
    df = pd.read_gbq(query,project_id=project_name,dialect='standard')
    return df
```

but this line give me error when I call the function:  `table_name =  str_join('inst_pic',{*which_src},{*which_dim})`. to me, logic is fine, `*args` should give is  parameter value, so that way we can concatenate the string, I got syntax error instead.

this is my another approach by using `**kwargs`:

```
def _readbqTble2(**kwargs):
    def str_join(*args):
        return '_'.join(map(str, args))
    for _, v in kwargs.items():
        table_name=str_join('inst_pic',v)

    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        query = "select * from `{k}.{k}.{table_name}`".format(kwargs,table_name=table_name)
        df = pd.read_gbq(query,project_id=project_name,dialect='standard')
        return df

if __name__=="__main__":
    _readbqTble2(project_name='fb', dataset_name='iris', which_dim='lifespan', which_src='asia')

    _readbqTble1
```

but this line `query = "select * from` {k}.{k}.{table_name}`".format(kwargs,table_name=table_name)` also give me error instead. I feel like `**kwargs` could be better way here. Can anyone point me out what went wrong here? what's the best way to read data based on parameter value in python?

**use case**:

I have those tables names listed in bigquery such as:

```
fb.iris.inst_pic_asia_lifespan
fb.iris.inst_pic_asia_others
fb.iris.inst_pic_europe_lifespan
fb.iris.inst_pic_europe_others
```

basically, I want to read specific table depends on the argument that we passed. I want my function be more parametric so can handle any file I want to read based on argument values that we passed.

Can anyone suggest any elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have confusion over the how `*args` and `**kwargs` works in general. Please see [this article](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/) to help you demystify. You can also see this SO answer: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

Working version of your code with inline comments:

```py
def _readbqTble1(which_dim="lifespan", which_src="asia", **kwargs):
    def str_join(*args):
        return "_".join(map(str, args))

    # `*args` takes all arguments in the call-list, and puts it in a tuple
    # Thus, you shouldn't wrap your `which_src` in a set like `{which_src}`,
    # just simply pass the string in the call-list.
    table_name = str_join("inst_pic", which_src, which_dim)
    
    # `**kwargs` will "unpack" all kv's in the call-list to `_readbqTble1` as if
    # they were passed as k=v arguments to string.format below.
    query = "select * from `{project_name}.{dataset_name}.{table_name}`".format(
        table_name=table_name,
        **kwargs,
    )
    df = pd.read_gbq(query, project_id=kwargs.pop("project_name"), dialect="standard")
    return df
```